# Cannot reshape array using imageio. Why?

Tags: python, python-imageio

I'm trying to mimic what this line of code does, using `imageio` :

```
img_array = scipy.misc.imread('/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_5.png', flatten=True)
img_data  = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)`
```

However when using `imageio` I get:

```
img = imageio.imread('/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_5.png')
img.flatten()
```

Output: Image([212, 211, 209, ..., 192, 190, 191], dtype=uint8)

```
img.reshape(1, 784)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,784)
```

Can someone explain what is going on here, why is my image size 2352? I resized the image to 28x28 pixels before importing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RGB image has three channels, so 784 pixels three times is 2352. Shouldn't you save the results of `img.flatten()` in a variable? `img_flat = img.flatten()`. If you do this you should get the three color layers flatten to one gray-scale layer, then you can reshape it.

Edit: It's probably going to be easier to just use skimage in the same fashion you used the deprecated scipy:

```
from skimage import transform,io
# read in grey-scale
grey = io.imread('your_image.png', as_grey=True)
# resize to 28x28
small_grey = transform.resize(grey, (28,28), mode='symmetric', preserve_range=True)
# reshape to (1,784)
reshape_img = small_grey.reshape(1, 784)
```

Comment: I did try and save it, `img = img.flatten()` however it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I wasn't able to achieve it through imageio neither. See my updated post.

Answer (score 4):

*I know this question already has an accepted answer, however, it implies to use `skimage` library instead of `imageio` as the question (and `scipy`) suggest. So here it goes.*

According to [imageio's doc on translating from scipy,](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scipy.html) you should change `flatten` argument by `as_gray` argument.

So this line:

```
img_array = scipy.misc.imread('/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_5.png', flatten=True)
```

should gives you same result as this:

```
img_array = imageio.imread('/Users/user/Desktop/IMG_5.png', as_gray=True)
```

It worked for me. If it didn't work for you, perhaps there is another problem. Providing an image as an example might help.